# Making a Calendar and being able to add days/months/years using a function in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker

I want to be able to add and subtract months and years from a given date using windows forms c#. I am unsure whether I should use a DatePicker or just make the date a textbox entry. Is the anyway for someone to write a basecode that would help me get to the right direction. I also don't know whether I have to convert the date to a string or whether just changing it to an integer then adding values then converting back would work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :) [image: windows forms, output being on label7]

Comment: Note that C and C# are very different languages.  Do not use the two tags together.

Comment: Sorry! I thought they fell under the same category

Comment: Use the Datepicker and use this method for example [DateTime.AddMonths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is you can instantiate a DateTime variable, these already have a method which allow you to add days to a given Date, in that way, you would only need to pass the amount of days, using the textField, then parse it to integer, and that should work.

**Something like this:**

```
//This will be a substraction
DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);

//This will be an addition
DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
```

You can assign the date you got, to a dateTimePicker